# FileReader output undefined

Tags: javascript, html, closures, filereader

I have a function which takes blobs as input and spits out binary string(ideally it should)

```
function chunkBinary(chunkFile){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = (function(reader)
    {
        return function()
        {
            console.log(reader.result);
            return reader.result
        }
    })(reader);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(chunkFile);
}
```

I am assigning this function to a variable in another function

```
function showUploadProgress(){

    for (var i=0; i<chunk.length; i++) {
        if(chunk[i][0] != 'No Error'){
            errorUploadFiles[j] = chunk[i];
            j++;
        } 
            //j starts from 4 as chunk[i][0..3] has some file data and then the blobs start from 4
            for(var j = 4; j < chunk[i].length ; j++){
                var chunkInBinary = chunkBinary(chunk[i][j]);   
                console.log(chunkInBinary);    
     }
 }
```

The problem is that the value of chunkInBinary is always undefined and when I print it in chunkBinary function I am able to view it. I have tried to use closures but for some reason I could not get it to work. Please suggest.

Comment: `chunkBinary` returns nothing.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to return a value from the chunkBinary function?

Comment: I am returning reader.result from inside the IIFE. Isnt that right?

Comment: Bump! Any other input guys?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, chunkBinary() isn't returning anything right now (your `return result;` statement returns to nobody in particular as onloadend is called by the framework itself, so the value just gets thrown away).

Because FileReader performs an asynchronous read, you can't just return a value directly from it. If you want a caller to have access to the return value, you'd need to use something like ES6 promises:

```
function chunkBinary(chunkFile){
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = (function(reader)
        {
          function()
          {
            console.log(reader.result);
            resolve(reader.result);
          }
        })(reader);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(chunkFile);
      });
}
```

Then the caller would have access to the value like so when the read completes:

```
chunkBinary(file).then(function(binaryString) {
  // do something with result here
});
```